# Interpreting gdb output where FPE is occurring

Tags: fortran, gdb, gfortran

I am using the same instructions as provided in this URL - [Debug fortran code with  gdb](https://undo.io/resources/blog-articles/debugging-fortran-code-gdb/) and I am getting these messages -

```
Breakpoint 1, psiappsor (omega=1.80999994, 
pv=<error reading variable: value requires 31250000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, 
psi=<error reading variable: value requires 31250000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, nsq=..., rhoref=..., 
thetatop=<error reading variable: value requires 250000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, 
thetabot=<error reading variable: value requires 250000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, thetaref=..., 
coriol=<error reading variable: value requires 250000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, 
ua=<error reading variable: value requires 125000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, 
ub=<error reading variable: value requires 125000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, 
va=<error reading variable: value requires 125000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, 
vb=<error reading variable: value requires 125000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, 
a=<error reading variable: value requires 31250000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, 
b=<error reading variable: value requires 31250000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, 
c=<error reading variable: value requires 31250000 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, nx=249, ny=249, nz=124, dx=26437.7188, dy=27813.7012, 
dz=200.139206) at inv_cart.f:1226
1226         >              c(i,j,k))+(1.-omega)*psi(i,j,k).
```

Googling these texts or looking up previous SO Q/A's is not helpful at all. I can tell you that a lot of these variables such as pv, psi, thetatop, thetabot, ua,ub,va,vb,a,b,c are being passed in from the calling subroutine. 
Is that what is causing these messages ? I can post the full code associated with the breakpoint if required. What do these messages mean ?

Comment: I think that those messages are self-describing : GDB can not store values of large arrays. you can change the max-value-size before starting the program `set max-value-size unlimited`. for more details see [Value Sizes](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Value-Sizes.html)

Comment: @M.Chinoune - thank you. I set it but now it hangs after encountering FPE.